# AngularJS Expression in Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to have AngularJS evaluate an expression within model data?

HTML:

```
<p>
{{Txt}}
</p>
```

Model:

```
    { 
     Txt: "This is some text {{Rest}}"
    }

    {
      Rest: "and this is the rest of it."
    }
```

The end result would be: `This is some text and this is the rest of it`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `$interpolate` service to interpolate the string...

```
function ctrl ($scope, $interpolate) {
    $scope.Txt = "This is some text {{Rest}}";
    $scope.Rest = "and this is the rest of it.";
    $scope.interpolate = function (value) {
        return $interpolate(value)($scope);
    };
}
```

---

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-model="Txt" size="60" />
    <p>{{ Txt }}</p>
    <p>{{ interpolate(Txt) }}</p>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9UY62/)

Answer (score 5):

You can execute JS within the brackets:

```
<p>{{Txt + ' ' + Rest}}</p>
```

Or create a function that returns the text you want:

```
$scope.getText = function() {
  return $scope.Txt + ' ' + $scope.Rest;
}

<p>{{getText()}}</p>
```

Comment: OP asked whether the expression itself could be a part of `model` (not just binding).

Comment: Please see how he defines `Txt`.  Will your code produce the desired result?

Comment: Our goal was to allow the user to enter text with a handlebar expression inside their text.

Comment: @Jason In the future, to save everyone's time, please read up on the XY problem: http://goo.gl/taIqf
I'll see what I can do about getting the user to enter `{{}}`

Comment: @SomeKitten I am presenting a solution that doesn't exist to explain the problem I am trying to solve. This functionality is possible in handlebars already, but there is not a way to do this in Angular unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using javascript for the model you can do something simple like this:

```
var rest = 'and this is the rest of it';
$scope.txt = 'This is some text ' + rest;
```

And in the view, keep your `<p>{{txt}}</p>`

Alternatively you can string the expressions together `<p>{{txt}} {{rest}}</p>`