# Replace some symbols inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying realize English test web page like this: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbs20.htm

So, I have JSON inside controller:

```
var studyEng = angular.module('studyEng', []);

studyEng.controller('ExercisesController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.exercises = {
        'title':'Will / Be Going To',
        'description':'Using the words in parentheses, complete the text below with the appropriate tenses, then click the "Check" button to check your answers.',
        'exercise':[
            {
                "question":    "Michael: Do you think the Republicans or the Democrats (win) :i: the next election?",
                "answer":"answer 1"
            },           
            {
                "question":    "Jane: I think the Republicans (win) :i: the next election.",
                "answer":"answer 2"
            },           
            {
                "question":    "John: No way! The Democrats (win) :i:",
                "answer":"answer 3"
            }
          ]
    } 
});
```

And Angular template:

```
<div class="starter-template">
            <h1>{{exercises.title}}</h1>
            <p>{{exercises.description}}</p>
            <ul ng-repeat="exercise in exercises.exercise">
                <li>{{exercise.question}}</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do, is that change :i: from my JSON, to input field

Please, help me - how I can do that?

P.S. I'm pretty new in Angular and in StackOverflow too :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put the current working code in a plunker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some solution. I've made filter:

```
studyEng.filter ('inputForms', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var output;
        var inputFild = '<input type="text"></input>';

        output = input.replace (':i:', inputFild);
        return output;
    }
});
```

And then apply it:

```
<ul ng-repeat="exercise in exercises.exercise">
                <li>
                    <div ng-bind-html="exercise.question | inputForms"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I just don't know how to bind HTML only for this repeater, so I've disabled SCE globally:

```
studyEng.config(function($sceProvider) {
  // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
  // Do not use in new projects.
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you can do.

1. You can separate the question into two parts (assuming that there will be only 2 parts).

   ```
   $scope.exercises = {
   'title':'Will / Be Going To',
   'description':'Using the words in parentheses, complete the text below with the appropriate tenses, then click the "Check" button to check your answers.',
   'exercise':[
       {
           "question1":    "Michael: Do you think the Republicans or the Democrats (win)",
           "question2" : "the next election?",
           "answer":"answer 1"
       },           
       {
           "question1":    "Jane: I think the Republicans (win)",
           "question2": "the next election.",
           "answer":"answer 2"
       },           
       {
           "question1":    "John: No way! The Democrats (win)",
           "question2": "",
           "answer":"answer 3"
       }
     ]
   ```

   };

And after that change your template to:

```
    <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>{{exercises.title}}</h1>
            <p>{{exercises.description}}</p>
            <ul ng-repeat="exercise in exercises.exercise">
                <li>
<div>{{exercise.question1}}</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="exercise .answer" />
<div>{{exercise.question2}}</div>
</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

2. You can leave the question as it is (one variable) and create a custom angular directive, that will split the string by `:i:` and add an answer input between each part. This will not work correctly if you have more than one `:i:` in a single string. To work with multiple answer fields you will have to change the `answer` to a list `answers: [answer1: "", answer2: ""]` and add the corresponding answer field.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. I'm guessing that you only want one of the questions to be answered.

```
<div class="starter-template">
            <h1>{{exercises.title}}</h1>
            <p>{{exercises.description}}</p>
            <ul ng-repeat="exercise in exercises.exercise">
                <li>{{exercise.question}} <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" value="exercise.answer"/></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to use interpolate, as he [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23706244/966698)

Like:

```
function ctrl ($scope, $interpolate) {
  $scope.Txt = "This is some text {{Rest}}";
  $scope.Rest = "and this is the rest of it.";
  $scope.interpolate = function (value) {
    return $interpolate(value)($scope);
  };
}  
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input ng-model="Txt" size="60" />
  <p>{{ Txt }}</p>
  <p>{{ interpolate(Txt) }}</p>
</div>
```