# Angular - Expression with in Expression

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use expression with in expression as below.

is it possible to resolve expression within expression with double braces?

```
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[
{name:'Jani',exp:'{{10>20}}'},
{name:'Hege',exp:'{{abc>20}}'},
{name:'Kai',exp:'{{10==20}}'}]">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
  {{ x.name + ', ' + {{x.exp}} }}</li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Check this out [Link Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706006/angularjs-expression-in-expression)

Answer (score 0):

you can evaluate via `ng-if` statment
OR Via ternary expression

EX: `{{10 > 20 ?"Yup":"No"}}`

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to avoid using ng-init in this manner.  You should handle all variable initialization inside of the controller.  You also shouldn't be trying to evaluate arbitrary expressions in angular, you should know what you're trying to do.  If you provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish, we could help with that.

That being said, you can evaluate an arbitrary string as an angular expression using `$eval`.

```
{{ x.name + ', ' + $ctrl.$eval(ex.exp) }}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval

Comment: Thanks Fusion , I just ng-init to explain issue which I am facing, in actual code what I am trying , the data comes from controller with http get service, I am stuck resolving expression inside expression

Comment: Why are you having these expressions?  It would probably be best to perform the logic when you receive the data from the service.

Comment: Problem is, I am using attribute of a directive and trying to resolve the expression in ng-class with expression in expression .. something like ng-class={'active': {{sal > 10}} }

Comment: Does the inside expression change? You could use the onInit function to evaluate the expression in the controller